# React can't unlisten history change

Tags: reactjs, browser-history

I have a react app and I'm using the [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package for handling browser history, such as pushing a new url/state to the history or listen to the history change event. The problem I have is I unlisten to the history change event in componentWillUnmount so that when the component is gone, the history change event will be removed too. However, the history change always occurs before the componentWillUnmout occurs, so I always get an error saying "cant setState on an unmounted component...". Does anyone have a solution here?

```
// browser_history.js
import History from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = History();
export default history;

// index.js
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from 'browser_history'; 
import App from 'app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// app.js
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(<Switch>
                   <Route path='/dashboard/' component={dashboard}
                   ...
                   ...
               </Switch>);
    }
}

// dashboard.js
import history from 'browser_history'; 

class Table extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.unlisten_history = history .listen(this.onHistoryChange);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.unlisten_history = history .listen(this.onHistoryChange);
    }

    onHistoryChange() {
        this.setState({...})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

Instead of using `<Route history={history}>` with a custom history object, use `<BrowserRouter>` and wrap components with `export default withRouter(xxx)`, so that the wrapped component will have a `this.props.history`, and I can use that to push new state to browser history, and that history object is always synced with any react routing actions.